# Exec не присваивает значение перерменной

Tags: python

В общем, я делаю программу, с помощью которой можно будет ходить по спискам в списке и смотреть содержимое в них.
Код:

```py
import os

class listTraveler:
    def __init__(self, array: list):
        self.array = array
        self.position = array

    def printElements(self):
        os.system("cls")
        print("--items--")
        for index, item in enumerate(self.position):
            print(f"{index} - {item}")
        print("---------")
        print("b - back")
        print("e - exit")

    def goForward(self, itemNumber: int):
        self.position = self.position[itemNumber]
        self.printElements()

    def goBack(self):
        pass

def main():
    array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, [6, 7, 8]], [[9], 10, [11, 12]]]

    traveler = listTraveler(array)
    traveler.printElements()

    while True:
        userInput = input(">>> ")

        if userInput != "b" and userInput != "e":
            if type(traveler.position[int(userInput)]) == list:
                traveler.goForward(int(userInput))
            else:
                traveler.printElements()
        elif userInput == "b":
            traveler.goBack()
        elif  userInput == "e":
            exit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Сейчас она может переходить в списки, но не может вернуться в прошлый список, так как у меня возникли трудности с реализацией.

Думаю, что лучшим решением будет функция, которая принимает список и индекс в виде строки, так как если это строка, то можно менять эти индексы. Вот функция:

```py
def func(array: list, index: str):
    item = 0
    exec(f"item = array{index}")
    return item

item = func([1, 2, 3, 4], "[2]")
print(item)
```

Но в итоге она возращает **0**, а должна была вернуть **3**. `exeс()` почему то не присвоил значение item, оно так и осталось равно **0**. Как это исправить? Или может быть другой вариант решения?

Comment: Какую проблему вы в принципе решаете? Зачем вы индекс в виде строки в квадратных скобках передаете? Очень похоже на ["проблему молотка"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/710/1365)

Comment: В общем, решаю я такую проблему: у меня есть список, в котором хранятся другие списки, и мне нужно их получить. В общем как то так: был у меня к примеру array[0], я прогоняю его запихиваю его в функцию с индексом 2, я получаю array[0][2]

Comment: а зачем вам отдельная функция, что бы пройтись по двумерному массиву? Используйте простой for

Comment: Мне не нужно проходится по двумерному массиву, благодаря индексу, который в виде строки, я смогу изменять его, к примеру перейти обратно в прошлый список

Comment: Вам не нужен индекс в виде строки, вы точно так же через индекс в виде числа можете обратиться к подсписку внутри функции: `array[index]`

Comment: @insolor, у меня есть переменная, в которую каждый раз присваивается значение элемента. По сути, индекс вводит user, и дальше переменная обновляется, так как он переходит в другой список, а значит другой элемент. User может выходить из одно списка и входить в другой. Поэтому мне и нужно менять индексы как в моем примере выше. Как то так.

Comment: Другого способа реализовать это я не нашел

Comment: Приведите конкретный пример с вашей проблемой в вопросе. Индекс в строке - это не решение, это костыль. Так делать не нужно. То, что вы другого способа не придумали, не значит что его нет. Почитайте ссылку в первом комментарии, это именно случай забивания гвоздей микроскопом.

Comment: Прочитал. Да, это походу именно эта ошибка. Окей, тогда добавлю конкретный пример.

Comment: @insolor, я вроде избавился от этой ошибки молотка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом вместо exec() вы можете использовать eval() примерно так:

```
def func(array: list, index: str):
    return eval(f'array{index}')
```

Но выглядит это если честно крайне неверно и простите за выражение глупо, просто используйте нативные возможности языка:

```
def func(array: list, index: int):
    item = array[index]
    return item


item = func([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
print(item)
```

Comment: `eval(f'global item; item = array{index}')` - в eval должна передаваться строка с expression, а вы передаете statement. Это выдаст ошибку синтаксиса. У eval интерпретируемое выражение должно давать значение (в отличие от exec). Рабочим вариантом будет `return eval(f'array{index}')`

Comment: Это верно, спасибо. У автора просто совершенно не ясно что он хочет

Comment: Это работает, спасибо )